# Capybara not finding elements with underscores in name

Tags: capybara

I am wondering if I'm missing something or if I've found a bug; hoping someone else can help.

I have a number of fields on a form.  All the ones that have single word names get found and filled, no problem.  All the ones with multiple word names do not.  Is this expected behavior?

example:

```
fill_in "Something", :with=> "value"
```

works

```
fill_in "Something Else", :with => "another"
```

does not

I've tried changing it to:

```
fill_in "something_else", :with => "another"
```

and that fails too, same message

```
"cannot fill in, no text field, text area or password field with id, name, or label 'something_else'"
```

I'm wondering at this point if Capybara is expecting _ to be boundaries and so it can't find them if they have multiple words like that.  Anyone else encounter this problem?  Is there a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After tinkering for a while  more, I found that the way to do this is to actually pass the full name attribute that you expect to be there (I guess the matcher can't infer which parts of the spaces are the object name vice the name of the property).  It follows the form:

```
fill_in "obj[one_two]", :with=> "value"
```

So let's say you want to fill-in a user registration form, it might be:

```
fill_in "user[password_confirmation]", :with => @password
```

given that you previously populated `@password`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but this worked for me in capybara (2.3.0) and might help others:

```
fill_in "Password confirmation", with: "test"
```

notice the lower case "c", this also worked in a nested form situation.

So from what I can gather only the first letter of the field name should be upper case if it contains spaces.